# Toggle CSS Classes using JavaScript - Error

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a Script that when a user clicks in an image with the class "burger-nav-img" it toggles the class "open" in another elements. My code is:

> HTML

```
<nav class="main-nav">
    <ul class="flex-container">
        <li class="flex-content"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="flex-content"><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
        <div class="logo_container flex-container">
            <img src="img\logo_background.png" class="logo flex-content">
        </div>
        <li class="flex-content"><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li class="flex-content"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
<a class="burger-nav">
    <img src="img/menu.png" id="burger" class="burger-nav-img">
</a>
```

> JavaScript

```
document.body.addEventListener("load", clas);
function clas() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("burger-nav-img").addEventListener("load", toggl);
}
function toggl() {
    const burger = document.getElementsByClassName("burger-nav");
    burger.classList.toggle("open");
    const main = document.getElementsByClassName("main-nav");
    main.classList.toggle("open");
}
```

The problem is that when I run this code an error appears and I can't figure out what to do:

> Console

```
menu.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined
    at toggl (menu.js:7)
    at clas (menu.js:3)
    at menu.js:1
toggl @ menu.js:7
clas @ menu.js:3
(anonymous) @ menu.js:1
```

Note: menu.js is the file containing the JavaScript Code;

What should I do?
Thank You For Your Attention!

Comment: what is this "open" passed in toggle function?

Comment: Your call to `addEventListener` is incorrect. You're passing the result of *calling* `class()` instead of just a reference to the function (`clas` without the `()`).

Comment: The "open" is the name of the class that I want to toggle.

Comment: Ok thanks I changed to what you said. But the error still remains appearing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements, and an array doesn't have classList property, and therefore you get undefined.

Use `burger[0].classList` or use an Id and `getElementById` that returns a single element.

Comment: Thanks the error has gone, but it still doesn't work. Any Idea?

Comment: You need to debug it step by step. Do you get the element you want in `burger`? Does the `toggle()` really toggles the class 'open'? If so, maybe there is something wrong in your css.

Comment: I tried console.log("OK") to test if the functions are running and they aren't being called

Answer (score 1):

`burger` returns a collection so you should do something like

`for (let i = 0; i < burger.length; i++) {
      burger[i].classList.toggle("open");
    }`

Comment: Thanks the error has gone, but it still doesn't work. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some research and a lot of attempts to solve the problem I finally got it.
 This is my final JavaScript Code:

```
document.getElementById("burger").onclick = toggl;

function toggl() {
    console.log("OK");
    var burger = document.getElementById("burger-nav");
    var main = document.getElementById("main-nav");
    if (burger.classList.contains("open")) {
        console.log("OKEY-DOKEY");
        burger.classList.remove("open");
        main.classList.remove("open");
    } else {
        console.log("OK-OK");
        burger.classList.add("open");
        main.classList.add("open");
    }

}
```

Thanks to Everyone who helped me! I appreciated It a lot!